# In Italy, how to know parking fee before driving into the parking lot?

Tags: driving, italy, automobiles

Is there a way to know the parking fee **before** driving into a parking lot in Italy? In many other countries there are boards with prices at the gateway, so you see the hour rates before you park. I have almost never seen such price boards in Italy. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

Prices should be clearly marked and visibly displayed by law. Failing this you can try using [Parkopedia](https://en.parkopedia.com/) which tends to keep up to date with parking prices around the world.

Comment: Clearly marked doesn't mean you'd be able reading them before taking a turn into parkhouse....

Comment: They are displayed. But inside the parking house at the payment machine. So it's not much help.

Answer (score 3):

Usually there is a parking payment machine (usually column-like urban structure like [this one](https://icdn-2.motor1.com/images/mgl/MAmXY/s1/copertina-strisce-blu-cosa-succede-se-il-bancomat-del-parcometro-non-funziona.jpg))

where prices are written usually in the pattern of

- 30 min payment fee
- First hour fee
- Next hours fee (repeated for each hour).

Usually paid parking have blue stripes and free ones are white, unless white ones are residential parkings for people who live there, in which case you will notice usually cars parked there will have some kind of ticket/permission with a letter on it to show they're actually people who live and park there and there should be a sign with the parking rules in the whereabouts.

[Here](https://image.prntscr.com/image/0kPF7mSMQ7GEua3yzPfV_w.png) is an example of price label shown on such parking payment devices.

Comment: I am speaking about other parking places. Not along the street but inside a parking house or a large parking space where you drive over a boom barrier and take a ticket.

Comment: To get the information you want, you usually have to ask to the personnel of the parking lot, or check to the entrance for parking prices labels or, try to to find the exit and find a similar machine to the one I show you in the answer with prices on it.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have an example of where you didn't find such information?

I don't know exactly which parking lots you are referring to, but when you have that kind of parking lot where you take a ticket at the entrance, you also have a sign telling you what is the hour rate. This is a common type of parking also in italy and, as everywhere in the world, we have the prices shown at the entrance.

There could be exception to that, as sometimes I also saw abroad missing prices at the entrance, but they are just a small minority.

Comment: City parking house in Brixen/Bressanone, visitors parking at Pragser Wildsee to name two. You take a ticket and don't know what the price is. The only place I've seen prices before entering was in visitors center at Karersee/Lago di Carezza.